# How the following has been obtained?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

In one of the problem of calculus, my teacher directly substituted the following value in place of the following limit of integral:

$\lim_{\ n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n+1}f'(x)dx=0$

My question is whether there is any formula or he used any property  something else? I am not able to understand why the above limit of integral vanishes. Any help or hint would be appreciated? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x^{n+1}=0$ whenever $x\in [0,1[$.

So your integrand approaches 0 everywhere except at $x=1$, which is just one point and thus doesn't influence the value of the integral.

Comment: Thanks Wouter, it was a trivial point  though you explained well.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a Lebesgue integral, it's apparent by the dominated convergence theorem. If it's a Riemann integral, it can be proved by showing$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{A} x^{n + 1} f'(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
$$
for every $0 < A <1$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\{\alpha_n\}$ is a sequence of functions whose total variations are uniformly bounded on $[a,b]$. If $\{\alpha_n\}$ is pointwise convergent to $\alpha$ on $[a,b]$, then for every $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^bf(x)d\alpha_n=\int_a^bf(x)d\alpha$$
Clearly,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{n+1}=\alpha(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}0&\text{if}&x\in[0,1)\\1&\text{if}&x=1\end{array}\right.$$